# How to initialize many Views in ButterKnife in Android

Tags: android, butterknife

I want use **`ButterKnife`** in my Project. I use many `EditText` and for initialize this `editTexts` I use this code :

```
@BindView(R.id.registerCountryEdtTxt)
EditText countryEdt;

@BindView(R.id.registerDateBirthEdtTxt)
EditText birthDayEdt;

@BindView(R.id.registerGenderEdtTxt)
EditText genderEdt;

@BindView(R.id.registerFullnameEdtTxt)
EditText fullnameEdt;

@BindView(R.id.registerEmailEdtTxt)
EditText emailEdt;

@BindView(R.id.registerUsernameEdtTxt)
EditText usernameEdt;

@BindView(R.id.registerPasswordEdtTxt)
EditText passwordEdt;

@BindView(R.id.registerFacebookEdtTxt)
EditText facebookEdt;
```

For **onClick** I want use many views one click method, how can I use one **@BindView** for many views?

```
@OnClick({R.id.registerDateBirthInptLay, R.id.registerDateBirthEdtTxt})
void selectBirthDay() {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can group multiple `Views` into a `List` or `array`.

```
@BindViews({ R.id.first_name, R.id.middle_name, R.id.last_name })
List<EditText> nameViews;
```

And to access these `Views`, just access the position:

```
nameViews.get(0).setText("Text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try this:

Implement OnClickListener on your activity.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

//your edittexts

protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
edittext1.setOnClickListener(this);
edittext2.setOnClickListener(this);
edittext3.setOnClickListener(this);
...
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
        //your code
}

}
```